# Unable to connect to MongoDB upon deployment / production

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

My mongoDB connects just fine locally, then once I deploy to heroku, the connection URL becomes undefined. I have a .env file in my root directory, and a .gitignore which includes the .env. I need the mongo url to stay private, but I can only assume that this is why it shows as undefined in production...

**Heres the error:**
"MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string."

**Heres my require:**
`require("dotenv").config()
var url = process.env.MONGODB_URI`

**Heres my connection:**
`mongoose.connect(url, { 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e.message)
})`

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your variables  where your app is deployed. It is not accessible from your `.env` file that you used  while developing on your local host. If you deployed to heroku - here is a [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) of what to do. If it's not deployed to heroku, you can get an idea what to do next to make it work.

Comment: Thanks man. For anyone reading this in the future, I moved my important info to a .env, put it in a gitignore, added my env variables to heroku, then set my mongodb url to process.env.MONGODB_URI. I also required dotenv and called config() immediately after.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to do, Make that .env available for the production code, It can't access your local .env file.

Second is your mongo running on production ? mean availabe and accessible for the app through 27017 port ?
don't say it is running on your local machine.